# How to gracefully implement EventEmitter in Swift

Tags: node.js, swift

I am writing a `hiredis` binding to Swift and working on the async API part.

I would like to have something similar to EventEmitter in Node.js.

`objectToBeListened.on('event', (data) => { ... })
objectToBeListened.emit('event')`

Namely I hope only one "on" and one "emit" function for every class I have.

I currently use `enum` for all event types and `switch` in "on" function. An extra `struct` which stores all callback functions is introduced.

I could not implement an universal "emit" function: I just glanced the Generics part of Swift. But is it ever possible? It seems that Swift doesn't have variadic template.

Anyway, my prototype code is really ugly and hard to maintain. Is there any better way to implement an EventEmitter gracefully?

```
class EEProto {
    var A: Int
    var B: Double

    typealias EventChangeA = (Int, Int) -> Void
    typealias EventChangeB = (Double, Double) -> Void
    typealias EventChanged = () -> Void

    struct RegisteredEvent {
        var eventChangeA: EventChangeA[]
        var eventChangeB: EventChangeB[]
        var eventChanged: EventChanged[]
    }

    enum EventType {
        case changeA(EventChangeA[])
        case changeB(EventChangeB[])
        case changed(EventChanged[])
    }

    var registeredEvents: RegisteredEvent

    init (A: Int, B: Double) {
        self.A = A
        self.B = B
        registeredEvents = RegisteredEvent(eventChangeA: [], eventChangeB: [], eventChanged: [])
    }

    func on (event: EventType) {
        switch event {
        case .changeA(let events):
            registeredEvents.eventChangeA += events
        case .changeB(let events):
            registeredEvents.eventChangeB += events
        case .changed(let events):
            registeredEvents.eventChanged += events
        default:
            assert("unhandled event type | check your code")
            break
        }
    }

    func resetEvents (eventType: EventType) {
        switch eventType {
        case .changeA:
            registeredEvents.eventChangeA = []
        case .changeB:
            registeredEvents.eventChangeA = []
        case .changed:
            registeredEvents.eventChangeA = []
        default:
            assert("unhandled event type | check your code")
            break
        }
    }

    func setA (newA: Int) {
        let oldA = A
        A = newA
        for cb in registeredEvents.eventChangeA {
            cb(oldA, newA)
        }
        for cb in registeredEvents.eventChanged {
            cb()
        }
    }

    func setB (newB: Double) {
        let oldB = B
        B = newB
        for cb in registeredEvents.eventChangeB {
            cb(oldB, newB)
        }
        for cb in registeredEvents.eventChanged {
            cb()
        }
    }
}

var inst = EEProto(A: 10, B: 5.5)
inst.on(EEProto.EventType.changeA([{
    println("from \($0) to \($1)")
    }]))
inst.on(EEProto.EventType.changeB([{
    println("from \($0) to \($1)")
    }]))
inst.on(EEProto.EventType.changed([{
    println("value changed")
    }]))

inst.setA(10)
inst.setB(3.14)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like [FlexEmit](https://github.com/Dev1an/FlexEmit). It works very similar to the EventEmitter in NodeJS.

Basically you define your events as swift types (these can be any struct, enum, class, etc.):

```
struct EnergyLevelChanged {
    let newEnergyLevel: Int
    init(to newValue: Int) { newEnergyLevel = newValue }
}

struct MovedTo {
    let x, y: Int
}
```

Then you create an emitter and add event listeners for different types of events you want to listen for:

```
let eventEmitter = Emitter()
eventEmitter.when { (newLocation: MovedTo) in
    print("Moved to coordinates \(newLocation.x):\(newLocation.y)")
}

eventEmitter.when { (event: EnergyLevelChanged) in
    print("Changed energy level to", event.newEnergyLevel)
}
```

And finally you send your events using a simple emit function

```
eventEmitter.emit(EnergyLevelChanged(to: 60)) // prints "Changed energy level to 60"
eventEmitter.emit(MovedTo(x: 0, y: 0)) // prints "Moved to coordinates 0:0"
```